# selenim find_element does not work with safari

Tags: python-3.x, macos, selenium-webdriver, safari

I'm trying to find element from Safari with python, but the code will hang while finding element.

> macOS version: 14.1.2 (23B92)
>
> Safari version: 17.1.2 (19616.2.9.11.12)
>
> Python version: 3.12.0
>
> Selenium version: 4.16.0

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser_name = 'safari'
find_browser = True

if browser_name == 'firefox':
    firefox_option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    firefox_option.page_load_strategy = 'none'
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_option)
elif browser_name == 'safari':
    safari_option = webdriver.SafariOptions()
    safari_option.page_load_strategy = 'none'
    browser = webdriver.Safari(options=safari_option)
else:
    print('Wrong browser name!')
    find_browser = False

if find_browser:
    browser.get('http://inventwithpython.com')
    try:
        element = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'row') # Code will hang at here
        print('Found <%s> element with that class name!' %(element.tag_name))
        browser.close()
    except:
        print('Was not able to find an element with that name.')
```

When I changed to Firefox, the code worked.

No error information, the code will hang while find_element.
[Screen Shot of VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzG2m.jpg)

python3 selenium_try.py
[Screen Shot of Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zty6a.png)

Comment: Where is safari_servic defined?

Comment: I tried to add the following code:

safari_service = Service('/usr/bin/safaridriver')

Comment: forgot to remove it after tried the safari_service solution

Comment: Removing it maybe is ok

Comment: I tried to remove it, still has the problem

Comment: Please provide error information.

Comment: No error information, I uploaded an screen shots of vscode

Comment: I want to check you run it real status ,`python3 selenium_try.py`

Comment: Uploaded the screen shots of terminal

Comment: Why doesn't your console start a new line? Have you found the reason by debug? 
I'll give it a try on my mac when I have time.

Comment: I've no idea T_T